# Adding new view into another subview

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am learning iOS.  I m using Xcode 4.3.2 , and i have created a button, and in the callback, i have used the following code.

1) Created single view application
2) creating a new view -> newV
3) creating a button but;
4) adding but as a subview of newV.
5) adding newV as a subview of main view.

```
-(IBAction) submitButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@" Submit Button is pressed ");
    UIView *newV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    newV.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];

    UIButton *but = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [but setTitle:@"SubView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newV addSubview:but];
    [self.view addSubview:newV];

}
```

But the problem i get is, only the view viewV is shown, but button is not shown. How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: just use initWithFrame instead of init for UIButton and it will show on your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the button, you didn't provide a frame.  Try using:

```
UIButton* but = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
```

When you created the button, it was of zero size, so you couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the button after adding in the view newV.

Comment: i changed as your suggested, but still not able to see the button.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question, and I was thinking that the button was part of the main view.I noticed there isn't a frame for the button.